# Restrict the text length assigned for Link Button from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some text being fetched from the DB, which I am binding to the DataList `ItemTemplate` in the following form:

`<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("url")%>' />`

The text that is fetched from the DB might be long and I want to restrict it to (let's say 50 chars at max. with a ... afterwards) in the above `eval` assignment.

How can this be done here?
Secondly, how do I specify the link here in `LinkButton` so that on clicking on it, it goes to the specified, the link should open in a new window as in `taget=_blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `a` tag directly

```
<a href='<%#Eval("url")%>' taget=_blank> <%# BindText(Eval("url"))%></a>
```

Codebehind:

```
public string BindText(obj url)
{
 if(url!=null) {return (url.ToString().length > 50) ? url.ToString().Substring(0,50) + '...': url.ToString() ;}
 return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to handle that would be to create a "Truncate" extension of type String which simply strips X characters from the end of it.

Regarding "target=_blank" - you should be able to accomplish this with the [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) property of the LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the target browser, using CSS `text-overflow` is an elegant way to do this at the client instead of the server (maximizes space; only that text which must be truncated will be truncated, and it also takes into account simple punctuation rules).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow

[This blog post](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/02/string-extension-methods-for-truncating-and-adding-ellipsis/) shows a decent solution in that it seeks whitespace in which to inject the ellipses (rather than blind truncation).

For setting the target of a LinkButton...

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" target="_blank">
```

ASP.Net will (usually) ignore attributes that it doesn't recognize and just render them to the client verbatim. However, this won't actually work because a `LinkButton` is meant to initiate a postback. You can use an anchor tag instead.